# Почему Telebot плохо работает с сериализацией?

Tags: python, json, telebot

Я пишу телеграм-бота на python 3.8, используя pyTelegramBotAPI (он же telebot). В процессе необходимо сохранять данные, вводимые пользователем, для чего я решил использовать встроенную библиотеку json. В тестах все работает замечательно, однако когда тот же код запускается вместе с ботом, он перестает различать адрес файлов. К примеру, есть объект:

```
time_data = {
    'start_time': {
        'hour': 4,
        'minute': 12
    },
    'set_time': {
        'hour': 12,
        'minute': 0
    }
}
```

Этот объект я сохраняю в файл "time_data.json":

```
with open('time_data.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(time_data, file)
```

Файл появляется в файловой системе и спокойно читается. Однако когда я хочу десериализовать этот файл в коде бота, он брыкается, говоря, что нет такого файла.
При этом он может создать новый файл и потом с ним работать, успешно сохраняя данные между сессиями. Но уже этого файла в файловой системе нигде нет. Куда он сохраняет данные? Почему не может обнаружить уже существующий, но созданный вручную?

Comment: «Куда он сохраняет данные?» — в текущий рабочий каталог, и telebot тут вообще ни при чём

Comment: Поместите Python-файл в тот же каталог, где создаётся `time_data.json`

Comment: `однако когда тот же код запускается вместе с ботом, он перестает различать адрес файлов` Как вы запускаете бота?